# How to use Ruby code inside js.erb?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, ujs

I'm able to render partial inside a modal using `escape_javascript` in js.erb file code:

```
$("body").append("<%= escape_javascript(render partial: 'example_partial') %>");
$('#my_modal').modal('show');
```

However, I can't seem to get results for:

```
console.log(<%= @error %>)
```

Comment: You need to put inverted commas around the ruby helper. `console.log('<%= @error %>') `

Comment: That's right thanks. My bad

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ERB will output a plain string. JS needs inverted commas around a string for it to be recognized. You have missed them on your `console.log()` statement.

Change it to:

```
console.log('<%= @error %>');
```

You may also find the `raw` helper useful. This will call `.to_s` and `.html_safe` on any erb output:

```
console.log('<%= raw @error %>');
```

Read more about `html_safe` [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/String.html#method-i-html_safe).

Comment: "inverted commas" — first time I hear that one... don't we say "single quoted strings" instead?!

Comment: I guess they look the same whether they're one of the other